# Best practice when deplyoying a Flink Job Cluster on Kubernetes regarding savepointing and updating the job

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am looking into a deploying a Flink job on Kubernetes. When looking through the documentations I'm having a hard time coming up with what the best practices are regarding how to deploy the job specifically when the job has to maintain state.

There are two main points regarding this job:

1. It is a streaming job dealing with unbounded data (never ending stream)
2. Keeps and uses state that needs to be maintained over different job versions

Currently, we are running on Hadoop. There it is quite easy when you want to deploy a new version of the job and keep state. The steps are: cancel the job with savepoint, then deploy a new job and point to that savepoint.

Kubernetes:

Based on the definitions, it seems that for our use case a Job Cluster is the best fit for the requirements. There will only be one job running on this cluster.

The issue with the Kubernetes setup is that the savepoint location needs to be added as an argument to the Deployment. In the case that a pod is taken offline, it will restart the application with the original savepoint in the Deployment. Specifically this will reset the Kafka offset to whenever the job was deployed and reprocess a lot of data.

In addition to that, how would i go about canceling a job with savepoint when running on a Job cluster from something like ci/cd? Would i need to create another deployer pod and use the rest api?

What is the best practice regarding deploying a stateful Flink job on kubernetes and upgrading it without losing the state?

Comment: I'm currently trying to find a good approach for that. The kubernetes `PreStop` hook would be good to trigger stopping the job with a savepoint (using the Flink CLI interface). Unfortunately, it didn't work. `CheckpointException: Not all required tasks are currently running.`. I assume that this happens because the service endpoint are disabled and the jobmanager cannot communicate to the taskmanagers anymore

Comment: I have the same question. Now I have two flink job. The first one is deployed as session mode on K8s, which can operated like deployed on yarn. The second one is deployed as application mode on K8s. And I haven't found a good way to stop or upgrading the job without losing not triggered data in windows.